# 'Having been released in ...' or 'Released in ...'? Is the Perfect Participle Necessary?

Tags: ellipsis, perfect-constructions, participle-clauses, perfect-aspect, participle-phrases

Admittedly, there are a few questions similar to this, but I find that the examples are usually compromised by other errors.

In these two examples (below), which use participle clauses as supplements, which construction is more appropriate? The one that uses 'having been released' (the perfect participle) or the one that uses 'released' by itself? They are both passive constructions that refer to a release that happened before the present state of 'is one of the highest-grossing films of all time.'

> [1] **Released** in 2009, James Cameron's Avatar *is* one of the highest-grossing films of all time.

> [2] **Having been released** in 2009, James Cameron's Avatar *is* one of the highest-grossing films of all time.

I know there is a tendency to avoid the perfect aspect when the temporal relation is clear, so I imagine these are both equally acceptable, with Example 1 perhaps more likely to occur.

If an answer can provide other similar examples and some theoretical framework to explain this, that would be very helpful.

Comment: ...such as ***Having been brought up by parents who were both teachers**, John learned to read at an early age*. If *Avatar* had been released 100 years ago, that might feasibly make sense on the grounds that having been released ***so long ago***, there would have been more ***time*** for it to have earned more money.

Comment: Fronted or not, the implication of *[something] **having been** [verbed]* is usually ***because** [something] [was verbed]*. But that implication doesn't suit the cited context, which is ***why*** it's non-idiomatic.

Comment: Interesting. I agree with that interpretation. There's definitely the implication of cause and effect. Would you say the same could be said if we changed the 'is' in my examples to 'was,' as in '[Having been] released in 2009, James Cameron's Avatar was one of the highest-grossing films of all time.'? Again, the context is that the state of 'was' is after 2009, perhaps 2013 or later.

Comment: MJ Ada: I think you're just posing awkward permutations for the sake of it. Bottom line, ***having [been, done, undergone,... X]*** normally implies a "cause-and-effect" relationship between the actual main assertion (John learned to read early) and the antecedent (being raised by teachers). Your example was already highly suspect with ***is***, and changing it to ***was*** just makes it worse. There's nothing to be learned from such random word shuffling.

Comment: Not at all. If it seems that way, I apologise. In my experience of studying English grammar, I have learned not to assume that everything functions equally across all tenses. Though I believed the use of the perfect participle would be the same in my 'was' example, I didn't want to jump to conclusions. Believe me, your extra insight is very valuable, even if you think it's superfluous.

Comment: I think it's important to note that there's only a *tendency* for the ***having been X'ed*** construction to imply a *causal* relationship between the past action/attribute it refers to, and the *main* statement in the containing utterance. You can adjust other aspects of the utterance (syntactically *or* semantically*) in ways that make that relationship less likely *in that specific utterance*. This doesn't affect the fact of there being a *tendency* for things to be otherwise.

Comment: Do you have an example? I can't think of one off the top of my head.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Lambie gave two examples where it wouldn't make sense to suppose that the "main" assertion somehow ***logically followed*** whatever antecedent was specified by a "fronted" ***Having...*** expression. So in those two examples, the "tendency" clearly wasn't applicable, which is why I commented and downvoted the answer. And in my comment, I gave modified versions of those two examples where this "default tendency" did in fact apply. What exactly are you still unsure about?

Comment: ...but it's not just ***Having...*** where this tendency applies. Lambie also gives the example *Painted in purple and blue, the room now looked very merry.* There's a kind of "because" relationship there, so the sentence is perfectly natural. But ***Situated at the back of the house**, the room now looked very merry* is "weird", because there's no obvious reason why those two elements should even be *connected*, let alone one of them *causing* the other. Note that there's nothing weird about *The room, **which was** situated at the back of the house, now looked very merry*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  You are not supposed to answer in comments yet you persist. Frankly, it's really not fair to the rest of us.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I didn't know you were drawing parallels with Lambie's answer, but now it's clear. Thanks.

Comment: I wasn't originally referring to Lambie's answer - but a mod has apparently deleted my first comment, which is what the now-orphanned ***...such as*** continued from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** Having researched this topic in detail, I am posting an answer that I feel best addresses my question.

In short, the perfect participle is not always required to indicate that the content of the passive participle clause happened before the time of the main clause. Past participle clauses that are already perfective (depicting a completed event), like 'Released in 2009,' are appropriate.

Additionally, 'having been' usually implies a cause-and-effect relationship between the supplement and the main clause, so it should be used to this effect.

Below is some supporting information:

**A Past Passive Participle Puzzle**

[This text by Tim Stowell](https://www.qmul.ac.uk/sllf/media/sllf-new/department-of-linguistics/hagit-borer-celebration/Stowell.pdf) gives a detailed (though not yet complete) account of the temporality of past passive participles. He talks about two types of past passive participle: stative (expressing a state/condition) and eventive (expressing an action).

> In standard passive constructions, the passive participle is temporally neutral, but in a variety of other contexts, it appears to express past-shifting, just like the past participle in the perfect construction does.

**Stative**

Stative past passive participles are said to be ‘intrinsically imperfective.’

> Imperfective predicates ... do not introduce new times, and they must typically be anaphorically linked to times that are independently expressed or implied in the surrounding discourse.

They happen simultaneously to the matrix clause (the clause in which a subordinate clause is contained) unless overridden by the insertion of a definite article, such as ‘the’ (shown in [2a]) or an independent time reference, such as ‘previously’ or ‘once’ (shown in [3a]).

See examples of statives below:

> [1a] We visited a natural arch *admired by geologists worldwide*. **(simultaneous)**

> [2a] **The** cat burglar *disliked by the police is drinking a cup of tea*. **(simultaneous or non-simultaneous)**

> [3a] We visited a natural arch ***once** admired by geologists worldwide*. **(non-simultaneous)**

**Eventive**

Episodic eventive past passive participles are said to be ‘intrinsically perfective.’

> [Perfective predicates] typically introduce new time points, and they
> resist being anaphorically bound by other time-denoting expressions.

Eventives strongly favour an ‘independent tense interpretation,’ which often leads to their taking place before the time of the matrix clause. However, there are some cases where the time of the eventive can be simultaneous with the matrix clause, such as in [4a]. The participle clause and the main clause in [4a] are said to ‘accidentally coincide’ because of ‘the independent past-shifted interpretation combined with past tense in the main clause.’

The fact that eventives can be simultaneous under the correct circumstances leads to another point: ‘habitual [eventives] behave like statives.’ They are imperfective—that is, they don’t convey a completed action.

> … the habitual/dispositional modality can combine with a perfective predicate to make it imperfective.

In the context of the past and future, eventive verbs can be either episodic or habitual, but when the present tense locates an eventuality at speech time, eventive verbs are usually interpreted as habitual—for example, ‘Cigarettes *are smoked* by women.’ Not all present-tense eventive verbs follow this interpretation, however: when used in a context that doesn’t express simultaneity with speech time (like a book or a newspaper), they can be interpreted as episodic, such as in ‘A cigarette *is smoked* by Zeina.’

See examples of eventives below:

> [4a] *Hired by Grandma to manage the apartment building*, George was raised in an immigrant family in Boston. **(non-simultaneous)**

> [5a] *Attacked by the Ukrainian resistance*, the Russian army units were strung out along a highway, waiting to refuel. **(simultaneous or non-simultaneous)**

**Speech Time and Given Time**

The temporality of a past passive participle can be inferred from the time of the matrix clause or the speech time. Participles containing eventives ‘favour independent tense interpretations,’ while statives have a ‘need to be anaphorically linked to an independently given time’ (the time of the matrix clause).

[4a] shows an overt example of an interpretation from the perspective of speech time (that is, the present), with ‘Hired by Grandma to manage the apartment building’ strongly implied to take place after ‘George was raised in an immigrant family in Boston.’

**Alternate Interpretations of the Eventive**

It should be mentioned that despite the eventive strongly favouring an independent tense interpretation, Stowell evidences that on some occasions, the interpretation ‘tolerates [shifting] relative to the matrix event time.’

Concerning indirect reported speech, he talks about *de re* (‘a description contributed by the speaker’) and *de dicto* (a description ‘attributed to the attitude holder’). He says that ‘an independent tense interpretation … is possible only if the finite or reduced relative clause is understood *de re*’ and that ‘if the relative clause has a *de dicto* interpretation … the eventuality time of the relative clause must precede the time of the [report].’

Consider the following examples of eventives:

> [6a] Mario told us that George, *ordered by grandma to lower our rent*, wanted to evict us. **(non-simultaneous)**

> [7a] We will be asleep in a hotel *struck by lightning*. **(simultaneous or non-simultaneous)**

In [6a], the order can be located after the time of the report if it is perceived as coming from the speaker, but in the *de dicto* interpretation, ‘Grandma’s order to lower the rent must occur prior to Mario telling us about George’s desire to evict us.’

As regards [7a], Stowell says, ‘It clearly allows both types of past-shifted interpretation (relative to speech time or main clause eventuality time).’ He also says that ‘it probably also allows a simultaneous interpretation synonymous with [“We will be asleep in a hotel that is struck by lightning”],’ which is said to ‘have an interpretation directly analogous to [some] reduced when-clauses.’ Stockwell does mention, however, that the simultaneous interpretation ‘seems less natural.’

**The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language**

Here is some supporting information from *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* by Huddleston and Pullum, taken from Chapter 14, 9 (Non-finite Clauses as Modifiers and Supplements, pp.1264–1266).

First, an example similar to Example 1:

> [8a] **Born in Aberdeen**, Sue had never been further south than Edinburgh.

Next, a short extract talking about how participle clauses such as these relate to the main clause (I have made the terminology easier to understand for those who aren't familiar with certain grammatical terms):

> In [these types of participle clauses], there [is not] any explicit indication of the semantic relation between the [participle clause] and the [main clause]. This has to be inferred from the content of the clauses and/or the context.

The passage continues to talk about how the interpretation of the participle clause could be temporal, causal, and so on. This ties into what some of the answers discuss—that is, the cause-and-effect inference of the perfect participle.

There is no mention here of the participle clause always having to exist temporally alongside its anchor (the main clause) when not in the form of a perfect participle. In fact, the example I have selected proves that it doesn't in this case; unless the sentence is saying that Sue had just been born and had never gone beyond Edinburgh as a newborn (an unlikely reading), we can surmise that Sue is probably not a baby anymore at the time of the main clause and that 'born in Aberdeen' is merely supplementary information providing context as to why she hadn't gone further than Edinburgh.

The interpretation is identical to the below (my example):

> [9a] Sue, **who had been born in Aberdeen**, had never been further south than Edinburgh.

**A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language**

Here is some supporting information from *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* by Quirk et al., taken from 14.8 (p.995).

They say the following about non-finite clauses:

> We recover meanings associated with tense, aspect, and mood from the [context of the sentence].

Here are some given examples of recovered meaning:

> [10a] (Since/Because/As they were) **considered works of art**, they were admitted into the country without customs duties.

> [11a] (If it is) **kept in the refrigerator**, the drug should remain effective for at least three months.

> [12a] (Since/After he was) **allowed unusual privileges**, the prisoner seemed to enjoy his captivity.

Comment: Considering that I wrote the question and have answered it exactly as I hoped it would be answered, I can only assume that the downvote is a result of someone disliking the fact that I changed the accepted answer to my own or fundamentally disagreeing with the content of the answer, all of which has been informed by expert sources. If it is the former, it should be mentioned that I changed the accepted answer so that it included all of the information requested in the question, not because I disliked or necessarily disagreed with the previous answers.

Comment: " the perfect participle is not always required to indicate that the content of the passive participle clause happened before the time of the main clause". I fail to see why you think this is important. How is "released in 2009" or "having been released in 2009" in front of or after Avatar a clause?? I dispute that.

Comment: This is a common point of contention. Using the view of traditional grammar, we would call them 'participle phrases,' so I can understand why you would see it as unimportant. If that is where your disagreement stems from, we're likely not going to agree on the answer to this question. My understanding is based on knowledge of participle clauses being clauses, not phrases. If you wish to know my viewpoint, I'd recommend reading the texts I referenced.

Comment: @MJAda: It's a bit long, but I've waded through it all, and can't see anything to disagree with. And pretty much *by definition*, unless there's anything demonstrably untrue (that I've missed), if you wrote this answer for yourself, it must be a ***good*** answer (for you, at least! :) And I'm not actually a learner myself, so I can't easily guess whether *another* learner asking about the same thing would find this exactly hits the spot. But my default assumption has to be that what suits one *should* suit another (even if not *always*), so +1

Comment: Thank you! I created a document for myself that contains the same information, so I figured I'd add it all to my answer so that everyone else had access to it without having to read 27 pages of text. I'm not a learner in the traditional sense (I can speak English fluently), so hopefully this is appropriate for someone less versed in the terminology. I've tried to simplify where I can, and I think the opening summarises the point so learners don't need to go trawling through all the details.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the "having been" in the Avatar movie sample sentence.
Other examples:
**Painted in purple and blue**, the room now looked very merry.
**Decried by some and praised by others**, the author did not look like a happy man.
OR
The room, **painted in purple and blue**, now looked very merry.
The author, **decried by some and praised by others**, did not look like a happy man.

Would there be any reason for using "having been painted"? It just sounds really old fashioned. A past participle phrase can be prepositioned to the noun without using a past tense when it modifies the noun. And then, it's **just an adjectival modifier phrase**.

By the way, no good editor would allow: *having been released* in the sample sentence as it is just dead linguistic wood, so to speak.

**Released in 2009**, *Avatar* by James Cameron is one of the highest grossing films of all time [in front]

The phrase needs to be next to the noun it modifies, in my opinion.

Also, this same sentence could be written thus:

James Cameron's **Avatar**, released in 2009,  is one of the highest grossing films of all time. I'm calling it an adjectival  phrase.

The  perfect participle construction (having been released) is not required with an active verbs such as **release a film** when the verb modifies a noun.

There are times, though, **that the perfect participle is needed**, as with copular verbs (be, seem, etc.):

**Having been** very rich, he now had to live on a paltry monthly stipend.

*Because one doesn't say*: Been rich, he now had to live etc.

Also, with certain expressions: having been made to look the fool.

Having been made to look the fool, John then proceeded to trip down the aisle and fall flat on his face.

That initial phrase can also go after John.

Comment: I don't find either of your ***having X'ed*** examples particularly natural, because neither of them contain any element of cause and effect - they're just using the perfect continuous to sequentially report one thing as having happened before the other.. Not really the same as the more common "consequential" usage: ***Having wasted his family inheritance,** he now had to live on a pittance.   **Having had too much to drink,** John tripped and fell*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I did not say having X'ed. I said: **Having been** + state. Having been rich, having been sick. But my main argument was about the film's release. I did not explain every single possibility apart from that.

Comment: But it's irrelevant whether the fronted adverbial is ***having X'ed*** or ***having been X'ed*** so far as the "consequential" implication is concerned. ***Having been sick,** John didn't come to my party* is fine, but ***Having been sick,** John lives in London* is weird. But WITHOUT fronting / continuous, *John, who has been sick, didn't come to my party* and *John, who has been living in London, didn't come to my party* are both fine.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I feel like you wrecked my answer by ignoring what I actually say and drowing it in comments about a seperate issue.

Comment: I don't get you. The entire question is about the difference between including the TWO words ***Having been*** at the start of the cited text. Your answer doesn't seem to address that - or if it does, it certainly doesn't include what I think is the most important factor concerning the difference (that the extra words imply a "consequential" rather than just a "temporal" relationship).

Comment: @FumbleFingers She asks whether "having been released" is necessary, as compared to just "released" and **that is exactly what I dealt with in my answer. No phrase with an **action (active) verb** and direct object requires "having been" as I showed in my answer.  To release a film, to paint a house, to level off the floor, to direct traffic etc. ad nauseum.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This may be due to my poor framing of the question, but Lambie's answer is more along the lines of what I was looking for, as I would never use the 'having' construction in this context. What you have said is very useful in explaining why the second example is non-idiomatic, but I'm interested in knowing why the first example is correct given my belief that present- and past-participle clauses used as supplements happen simultaneously (in most cases) to the main clause to which they're attached.

Comment: @MJAda: But as I keep pointing out, your reference to a "tendency to avoid the perfect aspect when the temporal relation is clear" is completely irrelevant to why it's not a good idea to prepend ***Having been*** to your example sentence! The entire reason your second version is no good is because there's no causal connection between the two "statements". Anyway, I've had enough of this question now. I've posted an actual answer; let people react and vote as they may.

Comment: @MJAda I explained why the first works. It is not a present participle or past participle *clause*: It is a phrase using a past participle as an adjective, and which must come before or after the noun it modifies.  You have not even reacted to that.

Comment: https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/mechanics/gerunds_participles_and_infinitives/participles.html However, since they [participles] function as adjectives, participles modify nouns or pronouns. [So do participle phrases]  There are two types of participles: present participles and past participles.

Comment: Circling back to your comment about the ‘adjective phrase,’ which I apologise for ignoring, I tend to follow CGEL’s assessment of such constructions (clauses). But yes, if we take them as phrases, it is easier to justify the perspective.

Comment: @MJAda "CGEL’s description of adjuncts is not entirely clear about the division between modifiers and supplements in clause structure (see, for instance, similarities highlighted on p. 1360). As a default, we take adjuncts of time, place, manner, condition, reason, and so on to be
modifiers—even when offset by a comma".  https://people.cs.georgetown.edu/nschneid/p/cgel-guidelines.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The Perfect aspect (particularly as *Having **been** X'ed*, and even more particularly when "fronted") normally implies a ***causal*** relationship, not just a temporal one. One thing followed the other as a ***consequence***; it didn't just occur later in time. For example...

3a: *Having eaten nothing for days, he was starving*

...makes sense, but although it's perfectly *grammatical*...

3b: *Having taken off his shirt, he was starving*

...*doesn't* make sense unless we're in some really strange context where taking off one's shirt has some kind of close connection to eating.

IMHO, OP's example 2 is like my example 3b - it's weird.

Comment: "having been released" for the film one is not necessary.

Comment: I would say ***having been*** is much worse than "not necessary" - it's positively non-idiomatic in the exact cited context. But there's nothing remotely odd about ***released** in 2009* - it's a potentially interesting bit of ancillary / parenthetical information, presented in a way that doesn't invite us to draw a causal connection.

Comment: You fail to point out that verbs with direct objects like "the film was released in 2009" IX released the film in 2--9) though passive can always become adjectival.

Comment: @FumbleFingers To expand on your answer, as I feel it addresses (helpfully, I should add) one half of the issue (that is, the correct use of the 'having' construction), could you perhaps explain how the past-participle clause functions temporally? My confusion stems more from the belief that past-participle clauses as supplements should coincide with (or be very close to) the action of the main clause. For example, 'Distracted by the crowd, the goalkeeper failed to notice the ball flying into the net.' Here we can safely say that the goalkeeper is being distracted as the goal is being scored.

Comment: MJAda: Forget about the "temporal" connection. In your goalkeeper example, native speakers wouldn't really know or care whether the distraction started (and perhaps even *ended*) before the shot, or only started ***as the goal was being scored***. It's not relevant - all that matters is we understand he didn't save the shot ***because of*** distraction from the crowd. The precise timing of the two elements relative to each other only interests learners who haven't yet understood that it's irrelevant, not native speakers.

Comment: ...that's because in this context, there's a "universal" metaphoric usage (which I think applies to ***all*** languages) whereby ***B follows A*** is extended to *follows in **time**, comes **after*** as well as *follows in **path**, comes **behind***. And that ***comes later in time*** has come to acquire "causal" implications even where the temporal implications are irrelevant. Anyway, there's no temporal sequence in, say, *John, **being a Dutchman**, came to my part* (probably nonsense) and *John, **a Dutchman**, came to my party* (perfectly okay in the right context).

Comment: @MJAda Same as your released example: Distracted by the crowd, the goalkeeper failed to notice the ball flying into the net. OR The goalkeeper, distracted by the crowd,  failed to notice the ball flying into the net. "distracted by the crowd" is a past participle phrase used as an adjective.